# SqliteCommand.ExecuteScalar() returns null (C# 5.0 and System.Data.Sqlite)

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, executescalar

### This code works!!!

DB path was wrong. Because of this, when I was executing:

```
dbConnection.Open();
```

Instead of opening my DB, I was creating an empty one.

Thank you all for your help!

---

### The problem

I am using C#.NET 5.0 and System.Data.Sqlite to create a console application that runs on windows.

I am trying to check if a table called "parcelas" exist on the database For that I am using this query:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='parcelas'
```

This query runs with no problems on DB Browser. But when I run it on my C# program the query returns "null" without any exceptions (for sure I have one "System.NullReferenceException" when trying to read the null result)

I tried casting the result object and calling .toString() without success.

¿Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the code:

```
public void TableExist(string tableName)
    {
        if (tableName == null || db == null || db.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR!!!");
            return;
        }

        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(db);
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='"+ tableName +"'";
        var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        Console.WriteLine("RESULT: " + result.ToString());
        return;

    }
```

Comment: I suggest you to check this code with a debugger and verify what value is really present in the variable _tableName_

Comment: I will test it now. Thank you!

Comment: NB: If this is not just a toy example but real code: Please replace the first `if` with proper checks: `if (tableName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tableName));`, etc. Think about your future self who sits in front of the customer's machine, sees "ERROR!!!" on the Console, wonders what the heck went wrong and curses your present self. :-)

Comment: Sure! for now, I am just testing. I will refactor for sure. I promise ^^

Comment: Are you sure that you don't get exceptions here? Because if the table name doesn't exist then you get null as result and calling result.ToString() should raise a NRE exception. Otherwise I find very strange that a query on a sqlite_master for a table name returns a row with null value.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain properly. The query does not generate any exception when executed. Trying to print "result" does. I will edit it on the question. :)

The point is that it shouldn't be null...

Comment: @Steve a row with null value would be `DBNull.Value`; instead, it seems to be returning `null`, which is: zero rows

Comment: Right, I see that the OP has added the info about the NRE. So it is working on an incorrect name or the db is not right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` returns `null` when zero rows are returned from a query; it returns `DBNull.Value` when at least one row is returned and the value in the first column is a database `null`.

So: your query is not returning rows. Check whether that is expected, and if not: fix it. I would, however, be **much** more concerned about the SQL injection vulnerability in `AND name='"+ tableName +"'";`; parameters should always be preferred.

Comment: I am confused about why executing the query in DB Browser returns a row... and why c# returns null (it is the same query)... 

Thank you for letting me know about that security issue, I will have a look at it. :)

Comment: @Iroqas question: are you looking at the same database? note that when you build and run your code, if you're using a file-based database (as opposed to a server-hosted database): you're probably now running against a different copy of the file, which may have different database contents (if you've done different things on the other copy)

Comment: Yes, I am sure I am opening the same file. I did no changes to it because it already contains all the info. My plan is to use it as a read-only database.

Comment: @Iroqas have you tried running `select count(name) from sqlite_master` in both the .NET code and in the DB browser? does it return the same number? is `tableName` what you expect it to be? I can't debug it from here...

Comment: I think you found the point. On DB browser it returns 5, on C# returns 0... This brings a lot of light to the issue. I am not very used to work with SQL! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Iroqas that strongly suggests you're looking at a different database...

Comment: ok... yeap. Entering the full path reveals the right result. OMG what a funny issue. Seems  C# code is creating an empty database in case nothing is found on the specified path... and the relative path was wrong... So I had a new empty database... What a noob issue hahaha. Thank you for your time!